# How to update database via HTTP trigger function in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have one problem to develop Firebase application. I wrote a HTTP trigger function to update database when it's triggered but not sure how to do it.

I think this is a quiet easy problem.

Thank you.

[EDIT]

```
exports.email = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

      functions.database.ref("test/appointment").once('value',(snapshots)=>{
        console.log('value is',snapshots.val());
        res.end()
      })

});
```

I tried like  above but it's not working.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post.

Comment: What you did there was write an http trigger that seems to have a database trigger embedded inside it.  That's not at all valid.

Comment: so it's impossible to access to database inside http trigger? I just wanted to know that. Is it possible to lunch express in it so that I can access to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doug mentioned in the comments, that's not valid.

If you want to access the database from your HTTP Triggered function, you'll need to you use the [Server Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). Your code would look as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.email = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

      const appointmentRef = admin.database().child('test/appointment');

      appointmentRef.once('value',(snapshots)=>{
        console.log('value is',snapshots.val());
        res.end()
      })

});
```